# Word for an old, cheap car you use in your daily routine instead of your new one?

Tags: single-word-requests

You use this car to avoid harming your new car, so you don't take that much care of it and you don't mind if you spoil it eventually, since it's old and cheap.

I saw this word on a YouTube video but I forgot it.

Comment: A beater; a hooptie (AmE)

Comment: A clunker.  Try looking it up.

Comment: [_Daily driver_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/daily_driver) is a common term.

Answer (score 1):

It's primarily British English, but here's [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/runabout)...

> *A **runabout** is a small car used mainly for short journeys.*

I note that they also say *In American English, runabout is used of cars with open tops*, and they have a separate definition specifically identified as US: *A runabout is a small, light boat with a motor.* So I'm guessing most Americans wouldn't immediately recognise the BrE without supporting context.

Comment: Already found it. It's "Beater (car)". Thank you for you effort.

Comment: Never heard of that one. I see it's in AmE Merriam-Webster, but they equate it with *clunker*, which I'd say is closer to our ***jalopy***.

Comment: @SeuMadruga A "beater" is an old, cheap car but not specifically a car that you use instead of your new one. Your only car can also be a beater.

Comment: ... while a runabout can be brand spanking new.

Comment: In BrE we use 'banger' rather than 'beater' for an old car. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/banger